# ProviderNotFoundException in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I am using a firebase authentication stream and using a provider to get any change this provider i have added to the root widget and now i am using a firestore stream to get another stream and usign a provider in home.dart and printing a list using this provide in another widget brewlist.dart if i am using provider then its value must be passed down to its descendents but its reflecting an error

here i get the error on my provider as

> Exception has occurred.
> ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> above this BrewList Widget
>
> This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider of your choice.

homescreen.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({super.key});

  final AuthService _authService = AuthService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider.value(
      initialData: '',
      value: DatabaseService(uid: '').brews,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade100,
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  await _authService.signOut();
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.logout))
          ],
          title: const Text("Brew Crew"),
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade400,
        ),
        body: BrewList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

brewlist.dart

```
class BrewList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BrewListState createState() => _BrewListState();
}

class _BrewListState extends State<BrewList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final brews = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot>(context);
    //print(brews.documents);
    for (var doc in brews.docs) {
      print(doc.data);
    }

    return Container(
      
    );
  }
}
```